# How to develop and deploy Catalyst fastcgi apps with nginx and custom URIs?

Tags: perl, nginx, fastcgi, catalyst

Probably it's not so relevant, but I'll start with my environment: Linux OS, Perl 5.10, Catalyst 5.80032, nginx 1.0.11.

For the sake of the question, let's suppose I'm using *mydomain.com* on port 80 as an access point for the app's web page. Also let's use `/var/www/mydomain` as the physical location of my Catalyst application. In this case the static content is located at `/var/www/mydomain/MyApp/root/`.

I start the application as a fastcgi server (from `MyApp/script`):

```
    > ./myapp_fastcgi.pl -l /tmp/myapp.socket -n 2 -p /tmp/myapp.pid -d
```

I start the *nginx* server with the following config:

```
    server {
        listen       127.0.0.1:80;
        server_name  mydomain.com;

        location / {
            include        fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO  $fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/myapp.socket;
        }

        location /static {
            root   /var/www/mydomain/MyApp/root;
        }
    }
```

and everything seems to work fine when I access the app as `http://mydomain.com/` or `http://mydomain.com/products` as another page (handled by `MyApp::Controller::Products`).

Now the challenge and the question: **how should be *nginx* configured so it could serve applications' pages with an URI prefix (for example `/some/prefix`)**?

In this case rootpage should be accessed as `http://mydomain.com/some/prefix/` and the second one as `http://mydomain.com/some/prefix/products`.

The second part of the question is: **how should be the application code modified in order to have valid URIs for redirects and all the pages?** i.e. how `$c->uri_for()` and similar methods should be (re)written to have the same behavior for prefixed paths?

I have tried the dummy straightforward adjustment

```
    location /some/prefix {
        include        fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO  $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/myapp.socket;
    }
```

but of course it doesn't work this way. So, I'm not able to get responses even to manually typed in URLs before moving to Perl code and play with redirects and URLs generation.

Answer (score 0):

There is in `nginx` such directive like `alias`. It works this way:

If you have a url with value of `http://my.domain.com/some/prefix/blabla.file` and use `alias` directive with `location` directive as follows:

```
location /some/prefix {
   alias /var/www/mydomain/MyApp/root;
}
```

The resulting url will be `/var/www/mydomain/MyApp/blabla.file`. Why? Because `alias` directive in `location` block use it's value (`alias` value) as temporary `root` for serving files and request and trim from request part matched in `location` so when request was `/some/prefix/blabla.file` here it will be only `/blabla.file` and when you add this to `alias` value then you will get what you want (if I understood you well).

**According to our discusion belove in comments I can propose two things.
First, in nginx you can add such `location` block:**

```
location ~ ^/some/prefix(.*)$ {
   rewrite ^/some/prefix(.*)$ $1;
}
```

This directive will delete `/some/prefix` from `/some/prefix/products` and leave you only with `/products`. Next change your `location` block to looks like following one:

```
location / {
    include        fastcgi_params;

    # Here you provide for your Catalys real uri which was orignally provided by user
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI $request_uri;

    fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO  $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/myapp.socket;
}
```

So you set param `REQUEST_URI` for your Catalys to has value of user request without any modifications. In `nginx` are to variables `$request_uri` and `$uri`. Value of this first one never changes and of the second one changes everytime when it's, for example, rewrited by `rewrite` directive. Moreover this will work because `location ~` has higher priority than just `location /` so request url will be always first trimed to only this what comes after `/some/prefix` pattern.

Will it be helpfull now?

Comment: Thanks for your intervention, but I have a more specific case with FastCGI and Catalyst framework involved. I know about `alias` and I doubt it is usfeul in FastCGI scenarios compared to static files. In Apache it could be done with `Alias` and `mod_fastcgi`, but nginx' `alias` is different.

Comment: what you means by telling it is different in nginx?

Comment: I mean `Alias` directive from _Apache_ is not equivalent to `alias` directive from _nginx_. What I'm trying to do with _nginx_ can be accomplished with _Apache_'s `Alias`, and my focus is on URLs that should be serverd by FastCGI, not the static content.

Comment: Maybe I missunderstood your question. Can you pls tell again what do you expect from `nginx`?

Comment: It's not a pure `nginx` question, probably that's why it looks not so clear. A Catalyst webapp dispatches URLs to _actions_ and I need `nginx` to transform the requests and FastCGI vars in such a way that the Catalyst app could keep working with _prefixed_ paths. If I'd know exactly what to expect from `nginx`, then probably I'd know how to solve it.

Comment: so if someone request for url with like `/prefix/prefix/blabla/url_that_i_know_how_to_perform` you would like to cut from it `/prefix/prefix/blabla` and sent to your Catalys only `url_that_i_know_how_to_perform` but to be this invisible from user side, yes?

Comment: basically yes, but it's not mandatory if there is something in Catalyst that could handle this .. and after all, don't forget that I need to know the real full URI so I could generate correctly redirects and other URIs